# Visual Studio 2015 No Bower Packages In Intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, bower

I have just download the Visual Studio 2015 Community edition and started to learn ASP5.

I have seen on many blog posts and videos, that when creating a new bower.json file you should be able to drop a line under the dependencies and a list of packages should start filtering as you type in the intellisense. I am however unable to see any of these packages listed, its also unable to find any versions if I manually type in the package name showing the only option as '*'. I have confirmed that the correct json schema has been selected for bower http://json.schemastore.org/bower.

I am running VS2015 on a windows 7 64bit machine and fully connected to the internet.

Looking forward to getting to the bottom of this issue.

Stuart

Comment: Try this: Close VS, delete folder at %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache then start VS again

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I have the same issue.  Tried your suggestion and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily at least both Bower and Node *version* IntelliSense started working for me after installing [Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have installed the above tool and am still encountering the same issue.

Comment: Bummer! Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

I also got only '*' as version suggestion for bower.json packages in VS2015 intellisense. (Node worked)
In my case it helped to update the "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools" VS extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it after installing the Corresponding Package from

*Tools* ->*NuGet Package Manager* ->*Package Manager Console*
->
PM>`Install-Package bower.js`

You can find more commands here ..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console